# How to use lit web components in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, components, web-component, lit

I make demo lit web components using npm .
i want to use that lit web component in wordpress.
how to use them in wordpress?

Lit components in wordpress..?

Comment: Load the javascript into Wordpress, then use the HTML on any page. Maybe first start with learning how to load any JS file into Wordpress, sounds like you are trying to take multiple unknown steps at once.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. I think the simplest solutions are these:

**Solution 1: Using Lit in Wordpress with Webpack or Rollup:**

1. Install and configure the bundler (Webpack or Rollup) in your Wordpress project
2. Install Lit
3. Create a Lit component and import it in Wordpress.

More info: https://lit.dev/docs/tools/production/

**Solution 2: using a starter kit to build each component**

1. Clone the official Lit started kit (https://github.com/lit/lit-element-starter-ts)
2. Build and bundle the component (`npm run build`)
3. Copy the bundled component (my-element.js) to your Wordpress project

Comment: Do I need to use Webpack? Could I just setup a Lit project, build the component and then export it as a web component, then embed it somehow into a WP page? 

I've never done this, but we need to build a static page and then add it to a WordPress website and I found this post in my research. 

Would be great if you could add more meat to your post. I'd Like it in return and perhaps others would too. :)

Comment: @misterhtmlcss, I hope the second solution helps you.

Comment: @ emanuel that's exactly what I was hoping you would say. Thank you for saving me rolling the dice. Now I know. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry I tried. I was even cheating thinking I'll try an HTML element widget that I am allowed to add anything into and I put it all into a single file WP widget and nada. I think I have fundamentally misunderstood how to do it in WP. 

I think I should put it on the actual server, then link to from custom header code both the JS and the data (JSON) and then in the custom HTML element, there is where I paste the <custom-html-tag></....>

yes?

Comment: Yes, you have to import the component file into your theme before using it.